# Metal: "Failed creating a default system device!" on iPhone5/iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++, metal

When I run the Metal sample projects on iPhone5/iOS8 they fail here:

```
m_Device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(); 
if(!m_Device)
{
    NSLog(@">> ERROR: Failed creating a default system device!");
    return NO;
}
```

`MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` returns `id 0x0` instead of a valid `id <MTLDevice>`.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal is only available on A7 devices.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear: Metal is available on iOS 8 and A7 chips. Or higher.

Details, also to OpenGL ES: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html